# How to detect if some text box is changed via external script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textinput

I have some jQuery plugin that changes some elements, i need some event or jQuery plugin that trigger an event when some text input value changed.
I've downloaded jquery.textchange plugin, it is a good plugin but doesn't detect changes via external source.

Comment: what do you mean by **via external sourse**?

Comment: Is there some reason you cannot use .live('onblur')?

Comment: @Miroprocessor I mean by some jQuery plugin or using javascript code.

Comment: @Darin Thanks, I've just tried it but didn't work!

Comment: really though, how would the text change by external source if not JavaScript?

Comment: I mean not by user, but by some java script code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MSS -- Alright, this is a kludge but it works:

When I call boxWatcher() I set the value to 3,000 but you'd need to do it much more often, like maybe 100 or 300.

http://jsfiddle.net/N9zBA/8/

```
var theOldContent = $('#theID').val().trim();
var theNewContent = "";

function boxWatcher(milSecondsBetweenChecks) {
    var theLoop = setInterval(function() {
    theNewContent = $('#theID').val().trim();
    if (theOldContent == theNewContent) {
        return; //no change
    }
    clearInterval(theLoop);//stop looping
    handleContentChange();
    }, milSecondsBetweenChecks);
};

function handleContentChange() {
    alert('content has changed');
    //restart boxWatcher
    theOldContent = theNewContent;//reset theOldContent
    boxWatcher(3000);//3000 is about 3 seconds
}


function buttonClick() {
  $('#theID').value = 'asd;lfikjasd;fkj';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    boxWatcher(3000);
})
```

Comment: Thanks very much.
 Unfortunately I think this is the only solution and if, then it is a huge weakness in the HTML & Java Script!!! :(

Answer (score 1):

try to set the old value into a global variable then fire `onkeypress` event on your text input and compare between old and new values of it. some thing like that

```
  var oldvlaue = $('#myInput').val();
  $('#myInput').keyup(function(){
     if(oldvlaue!=$('#myInput').val().trim())
     {
        alert('text has been changed');
     }
 });
```

you test this example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cTSeb/)

**Edit**

try to add an `EventListner` to your text input, I don't know more about it but you can check this [Post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) it may help

Comment: I saw this example, but this doesn't detect the 'external' changes!

Comment: I mean that if 'something' changed the value of the input text programmatically it would not work!

Comment: Thanks  @Miroprocessor, i think it is the same as $.bind in jQuery, but the problem is that there are no useful event here to bind to!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Darin because of his/her solution I've marked as the answer, but i have made some small jQuery plugin to achieve the same work named  'txtChgMon'.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.txtChgMon = function (func) {
        var res = this.each(function () {
            txts[0] = { t: this, f: func, oldT: $(this).val(), newT: '' };
        });
        if (!watchStarted) {
            boxWatcher(200);
        }
        return res;
    };
})(jQuery);
var txts = [];
var watchStarted = false;


function boxWatcher(milSecondsBetweenChecks) {
    watchStarted = true;
    var theLoop = setInterval(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < txts.length; i++) {

            txts[i].newT = $(txts[i].t).val();
            if (txts[i].newT == txts[i].oldT) {
                return; //no change
            }
            clearInterval(theLoop); //stop looping
            txts[i].f(txts[i], txts[i].oldT, txts[i].newT);
            txts[i].oldT = $(txts[i].t).val();
            boxWatcher(milSecondsBetweenChecks);
            return;
        }
    }, milSecondsBetweenChecks);
}
```